# Cachebuster query parameter sometimes does not give new output using BunnyCDN

Tags: caching, bunnycdn

I am using BunnyCDN for caching files. Files are updated regularly. To make sure every time user load those files they find new output, I have added query parameters with the request of that file, e.g.,

```
https://example.json?v=${day}.${month}.${years}
```

So every day the parameter changes, and I am expecting to get new output. But often I can see files are giving output four days before, even though files are actually updated.

Am I missing something? I do not want to use cache-control headers for those files. Then every after certain time the CDN will call to the origin server and there will be cost added. How can I fix this problem?

Suppose I am using `https://example.json?v=1.0.2024`. This URL is giving me old output even though I should get new output as per the logic.

When I use `https://example.json?v=1.0.2025` manually, it works.